# Command for Big Omega

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

How can I the code for "big omega", NOT `\omega` which is little omega. I want the symbol that's used in big-O notation.

Comment: You're probably looking for `\mathcal{O}` and/or `\Omega`.

Comment: Note that `\omega` is also used in [big-O (i.e. asymptotic) notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: To whomever down-voted the answers of Peter Grill, Werner, and myself (Mico): Would you please communicate what's so bad about answers? Enlighten us, please.

Comment: @Mico: I was wondering the same thing, especially since the OP was looking specifically for big-O notation.

Comment: @Mico: Obviously, the correct answer is simply one word, "`\Omega`", and it was already given in Tom Bombadil's answer – the downvoted answers are just misleading.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela: NP, but I am not 100% sure that all the OP wanted was `\Omega` (although that is the title). In the text he clearly indicates that he is looking for [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: @PeterGrill: The terminology is a bit sloppy; people commonly refer to the "big-O notation" when they actually mean the Bachmann–Landau notation, which uses the symbols $o$, $O$, $\omega$, $\Omega$, and $\Theta$. So $\Omega$ really *is* the "big omega" that is used in the "big-O notation".

Answer (score 22):

It's quite easy: `\Omega`. Also the other big letters just begin with a capital letter, e.g. `\Delta`, `\Pi`. I can also recommend [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), there you can draw something with your mouse, and and engine tries to recognize what you drew and presents some suggestions.

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\BigO}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{O}\bigl(#1\bigr)}}
\begin{document}
The symbol for Big-O notation:
\BigO{n}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the brackets to resize automatically you can use:

```
\newcommand{\BigO}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{O}\left(#1\right)}}
```

Comment: Strange. If I use your command, the O is not typeset in italics exactly as you show in the image. I have checked both [Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) and [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Special-3rd/dp/0201700735) and they both typeset the big O in italics. Is it correct to typeset big O in italics?

Comment: @Ali: I don't know if the symbol should be in italics or not -- that is not a TeX type question.  I suspect the reason yours is not in italics is due to some setup or package related issue.  I would suggest you post a new question and include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem, and you can reference this question.

Comment: There is no problem to be reproduced. The question is: Should it be typeset in italics or not? By the way, I get exactly what you got: it is not in italics and that is exactly what I see in the image in your answer.

Comment: This formula inserts a narrow space between `O` and `(`, which seems inconsistent with usual practice. In my own documents, I insert `\!` between them to close it up.

Comment: @TomZych: I belive the above is correct spacing for an operator. Do you also insert a `\!` following `\sin` as well?  Perhaps you should post a follow-up question as there others who are more knowledgable  to answer a question about how Big-O notation should be typeset.  Would be good to get a definitive answer so there can be a correct answer here.

Comment: @PeterGrill I’m not sure which way is more correct, really. I have two textbooks, both about 25 years old, in which big-O is typeset in italics with a thin space after. I haven’t had a chance to check more recent printed editions yet. Online, O() without a space seems quite common.

Comment: The space after O is not caused by `\operatorname`. Rather it is caused by using `\left` and `\right`. Therefore it should be removed. The space after `\sin` is only used if the operand is not in brackets.

Answer (score 7):

An up-front comment (not directly an answer, but I'll get to that soon): The Greek "little" o, or *omicron* (as opposed to the "big" o, i.e., *omega*),  is identical in appearance -- in both its lowercase and uppercase versions -- to the Roman letters "o" and "O". Hence there are no TeX commands for $\omicron$ and $\Omicron$.

To denote the asymptotic order of magnitudes "little-oh" and "big-Oh", respectively, one frequently encounters $o$ and $O$ (i.e., using TeX's math-italics font) and -- for big-Oh only -- $\mathcal{O}$. Most math fonts (including Computer/Latin Modern) do not have *lowercase* mathcal letters, therefore one generally does not see $\mathcal{o}$ for "little-oh".

Incidentally, the `mtpro2` package -- when loaded with the `mtpcal` option -- *does* have a symbol for $\mathcal{o}$. Unfortunately, the package is not free, but its cost (for noncommercial licenses) is very reasonable. The first line in the image below shows the results of $o$ and $O$, and the second line shows the results of $\mathcal{o}$ and $\mathcal{O}$ commands produced with the `mtpro2` package loaded.

[image]

Finally, I must confess that I have not yet seen the symbol $\Omega$ (uppercase-Omega) used in asymptotic "big-Oh" notation, but that may be just be a consequence of my lack of erudition.

Comment: $\Omega$ is used for *lower* bounds. E.g. all comparison sorts run in Omega(n log n) time

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
\newcommand{\bigO}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{O}}}% big-O notation/symbol
```

to your document (preamble) and then you can use `\bigO`. If you want to use `\Omega` instead to represent your biig-O notation, then add

```
\newcommand{\bigO}{\ensuremath{\Omega}}% big-O notation/symbol
```

instead.